# How do I find the adjacency matrix for the nodes of an n-dimensional finite grid?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I have an orthotopic grid, in n-dimensions (usually small ~<3), where each node is connected to it's orthogonal neighbours. The grid may be any number of nodes long, but is finite (and usually small - ~<10) in each dimension. The edges of the grid are undirected.

Given the grid dimensions (e.g. (3,4,3)), how can I generate an adjacency matrix for the nodes (1=edge, 0=no edge)?

Comment: Do you mean "How do I write a computer program to do this?" Or "How do I do this by hand?" If the former, in what language? (In Matlab, it's pretty easy, for instance). Finally, what's your ordering of your vertices? (And what do you mean by "matrix"? If you mean "a function from $V \times V$ to $\mathbb Z$", where $V$ denotes the vertex set", then this is a very easy question.

Comment: @John: I want to be able to do it by hand first, then in python. The matrix would be symmetric, of dimension `[n_nodes,n_nodes]`, where $A_{ij}$ gives the connectedness of nodes i and j, where i and j are a serialised form of the grid coordinates. I'm having some trouble with getting my head around the serialisation, but I'm nearly there. I guess the vertex ordering is dependant on the convention in the language that it's implemented in.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I worked it out, after a lot of trial and error. Here is the code that I'm using in python. **If there is a better way of doing this, I would happily accept another answer**.

```
import numpy as np

def _unserialise_coordinate(serial, spacing):
    coord = []
    for i in range(len(spacing)):
        coord.append(int(np.floor(serial/spacing[i])))
        serial = int(serial % spacing[i])

    return(coord)

def _serialise_coordinate(coord, spacing):
    return(np.dot(coord, spacing))

def _generate_adjacency_matrix(grid_dimensions):
    """Generate an adjacency matrix for nodes of an orthotopic grid with
    dimensions given by grid_dimensions
    """
    n_centres = np.prod(grid_dimensions)

    adjacency = np.zeros((n_centres, n_centres))

    spacing = [int(np.prod(grid_dimensions[(k+1):])) for k in range(len(grid_dimensions))]

    for i in range(n_centres):
        coord = _unserialise_coordinate(i, spacing)
        neighbours = []
        for d in range(len(grid_dimensions)):
            if coord[d] > 0:
                down = coord.copy()
                down[d] -= 1
                neighbours.append(down)
            if coord[d] < (grid_dimensions[d] - 1):
                up = coord.copy()
                up[d] += 1
                neighbours.append(up)

        for neighbour in neighbours:
            serial = _serialise_coordinate(neighbour, spacing)
            adjacency[i,serial] = 1

    return(adjacency)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "orthopic" grid is the carteisan product of $P_n$ and $P_m$ you can do it in a few lines with sage

> sage: graphs.PathGraph(3).cartesian_product(graphs.PathGraph(4)).am()
>
> [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
>   [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
>   [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0] 
>   [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0] 
>   [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0] 
>   [0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0] 
>   [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0] 
>   [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1] 
>   [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0] 
>   [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0] 
>   [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1] 
>   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]

Comment: What are $P_n$ and $P_m$? Does this extend to more dimensions? And what is it actually doing? (a link to the functions used would answer the last question).